# A base for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: general-topology

My question is, Can the family $\{[a,b]\times[c,d]: a<b, c<d\in\mathbb{R}\}$ be a base for a topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? I think not because if we take $[1,3]\times [2,4]$ and $[3,5]\times[4,5]$, their intersection is $\{(3,4)\}$ and $\{(3,4)\}$ can not contain a set of the form $[a,b]\times[c,d]$.

But what if $a\leq b$ and $c\leq d$ then, can we take the intervals $[3,3]\times[4,4]$ and can it be a base for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: A first problem is that, usually, a topology base is made of _open_ sets, not closed ones. It is of course possible to have a base for closed sets, but is it really what you want?

Comment: Do you mean for the standard topology?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni In the topology generated by that family, that sets would be open. By the way, "closed set" is not the oposite of "open set". A set can be both closed and open.

Comment: @jjagmath I know that. It's just that when seeing a question on math.stackexchange.com, the first thing to do is to clarify possible basic misunderstandings, before going deeper.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur The question ask if that family of sets is a base for **a** topology. There's no reason to think that the OP is thinking about the standard topology.

Comment: @Woodx Yes, if the inequalities are non-strict that family is a base for a topology of $\Bbb R^2$. Spoiler: That topology would be very simple and well known topology, it even has a name.

Comment: I did not specifically mean the standard topology, I meant a base for any topology. @Keen-ameteur

Comment: @jjagmath you mean the base has a name the "discrete topology"?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni actually I just asked that if  this family is  a base for any topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Can you give an example one to have a basis for closed sets?

Comment: Yes, but that not the name of the base. It's the name for the topology.

Comment: @Woodx Wikipedia has a good explanation and a convincing example (Zarisky topology): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Base_for_the_closed_sets

Comment: @jjagmath thank you

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. In order to be a basis, (1) every element $x \times y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ must be contained in a basis element, and (2) given two basis elements $U$ and $V$ and an element $x \times y$ in their intersection, there must exist a basis element $W$ such that $x \times y \in W \subseteq U \cap V$.

The set $A = \{ [a, b] \times [c, d] | a < b, c < d \}$ is not a basis. It does satisfy condition (1), since note that $x \times y \in [x - 1, x + 1] \times [y - 1, y + 1] \in A$ for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. However, as you mentioned, it does not satisfy (2) because it does not contain singleton sets, while the intersection of basis elements $[a, b] \times [c, d]$ and $[b, e] \times [d, f]$, for instance, is the singleton $\{ b \times d \}$.

If we relax the condition that the endpoints be unequal, i.e., $B = \{ [a, b] \times [c, d] | a \le b, c \le d \}$, then we do have a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Note that (1) is satisfied by the same reason as $A$ above. And, you can show that given any two sets $U, V \in B$ such that $U$ intersects $V$, that $U \cap V \in B$, so that (2) is satisfied. There are a few cases to check here.

Note that $B$ generates the *discrete* topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Recall that a basis for the discrete topology is the collection of all singleton sets $\{ x \times y \}$. But $\{ x \times y \} = [x, x] \times [y, y] \in B$, showing that the topology generated by $B$ is finer, indeed equal, to the discrete topology.

Comment: thank you very much for this illuminating answer sir

Comment: @Woodx The way you thank answerers is by upvoting and accepting answers and not by commenting "thank you" . Please take a look at your other questions and accept answers . Otherwise , those questions remain piled up in the unanswered section .